# insert patterns into text file after the last line

Tags: shell, awk

I use below codes to insert the lines after specific line into text file w.r.t. the user's variable.

```
echo -n "WHICH STATIONS?"
read station
echo ${station[${i}]}
awk -v input="$station" '
 BEGIN {
        n = split(tolower(input), user)              
pattern = " force %-4s npos 0. .0001\n" \
          " force %-4s epos 0. .0001\n" \
          " force %-4s upos 0. .0001\n"   
    }
    {print}
    /specific_line/ {
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
             printf pattern, j=user[i], j, j
        exit
    }
' ./data > data_2
```

I need to insert `pattern` after the last line of data file. How can I modify above codes?

Comment: I'm reasonably certain I voted to close this post for being cross posted: http://askubuntu.com/q/713702/158442

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appending this to the end of the `awk` script causes `awk` to execute the `for` loop before exiting:

```
    END {
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
             printf pattern, j=user[i], j, j
    }
```

If you want to print *all* of the lines of file `data`, then you should probably remove the `exit` at the end of the `/specific_line/` code block, because that causes `awk` to cease processing input and branch to the `END` block, if present, and then exits the script.